# TCP Client sending but not receiving and Server receiving but not sending

Tags: java, tcp

I have made a program in Java that allows the server admin to monitor the client processes. It's all OK when I'm sending data to the server. But, when I try to send data back, it just doesn't receive it.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
class TCPServer {
public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
    String clientSentence;
    String capitalizedSentence;
    ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);
    while (true) {
        Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
        BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
        clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
        System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);
        capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase();
        outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
    }
}
```

}

I found out the error, i was not sending an "\n" after the message, causing a pile-up and that never got sent.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
class TCPServer {
public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
    String clientSentence;
    String capitalizedSentence;
    ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);
    while (true) {
        Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
        BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
        clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
        System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);
        capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + "\n"; // <-----
        outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'm looking, but I just can't see it...

Comment: oh sorry forgot link lol

Comment: now it's here. I'm so sorry

Comment: It looks like your server never actually finishes sending a line? It sends "killpr" then leaves the socket alone forever. No newline, and the socket isn't closed. So readLine on the client never returns because it's waiting for the rest of the line.

Comment: ok ill try fix that ill let u know

Comment: Re-posting that as an answer so you can mark it resolved.

Comment: immibis i got another problem. how would i go about sending the message from another class/function?

Comment: Code relevant to a question should be posted *here* in a minimal form that demonstrates the problem. Otherwise the question is of no permanent value and is liable for deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server never actually finishes sending a line. It sends "killpr" then leaves the socket alone forever - without sending a newline or closing the socket.

On the client, readLine doesn't return because it's waiting for the rest of the line.

Comment: immibis i got another problem. how would i go about sending the message from another class/function?